# Control bash jobs as a group?

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to control a group of jobs within a given `bash` session?

Ideally, I would like to say something like:

```
$ prog1 &   
$ GROUP=FOO prog2 &
$ GROUP=FOO prog3 &
$ GROUP=BAR prog4 &
```

and then have e.g. `kill %FOO` terminate only `prog2` and `prog3`.

Answer (score 1):

**Is there a way to control a group of jobs within a given bash session?**

Yes there is! - Use arrays to form the groups, and capture each process ID using `$!` and append it to the array.

`$!` is a [special parameter specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02), which gives the decimal process ID of the most recent background command.

Below is a tutorial of how to append to arrays in Bash and enumerate them in the context of your question:

First declare the arrays:

```
$ GROUP_FOO=()
$ GROUP_BAR=()
```

Job that is not in a group:

```
$ prog1 &
```

Job to go in FOO group (the `+=` notation indicates that the value should be appended to the array):

```
$ prog2 &
$ GROUP_FOO+=($!)
```

Another job to go in FOO group:

```
$ prog3 &
$ GROUP_FOO+=($!)
```

Job to go in BAR group:

```
$ prog4 &
$ GROUP_BAR+=($!)
```

To kill the FOO group processes:

```
$ for id in ${GROUP_FOO[@]}; do kill $id; done
```

**Scripted version**

If I was scripting this, I would amend slightly so that the process ID is only added to the array if successfully starts:

```
prog2 & sleep 0.1; kill -0 $! && GROUP_FOO+=($!)
```

That way you will be less likely to have process IDs in your array which are not running because they exited immediately with an error. The 0.1 second sleep delay (could probably even be 0.01 sec) gives the process time to exit with an error code.